# What shows up on network printer log

Tags: networking, log-files, printing, network-printer

I sent a document to our HP network printer at work.  I just typed a doc in word, printed it, and deleted it.  Can it be recreated? What shows up on the log? The actual doc or just the time, number of pages and the computer it came from?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the network and the printer is setup. The System Administrator could have configured all of those including logging the entire document. They also may not be logging anything at all.

See your Systems Administrator for more information.